# Change scale variable into multiple nominal variables

Tags: spss

I'm trying to create an age variable then split this into multiple variables for aggregating several files together. I've been using the following syntax to split the Age variable into 9 age categories and it works fine, but I would like to split it now into 50ish variables. The ages range from 20 to 70 in the dataset so I would like to create 50 variables, age20, age21 etc with a 1 for the age variable that the person would be (ie I'm 25 for age25 my record would have a 1 and a 0 for all the other agexx variables). I know I could just use the below code and create 50 variables that way but is there a simpler way that would take the result of zz for Age and then put a value of 1 for agezz?

```
COMPUTE Date = DATE.DMY(31,03,2014) .
EXECUTE .
COMPUTE Age = DATEDIF(Date, DOB, "years").
VARIABLE LABEL Age.
VARIABLE LEVEL Age (SCALE).
FORMATS Age (F5.0).
VARIABLE WIDTH Age(5).
EXECUTE.

**create new variables**


IF (Age < 25) Age1=1.
EXECUTE.

IF (Age>=25 & Age<30) Age2=1.
EXECUTE.

IF (Age>=30 & Age<35) Age3=1.
EXECUTE.

IF (Age>=35 & Age<40) Age4=1.
EXECUTE.

IF (Age>=40 & Age<45) Age5=1.
EXECUTE.

IF (Age>=45 & Age<50) Age6=1.
EXECUTE.

IF (Age>=50 & Age<55) Age7=1.
EXECUTE.

IF (Age>=55 & Age<60) Age8=1.
EXECUTE.

IF (Age>=60) Age9=1.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create dummy variables for the age between 20 and 69 you can use the `DO REPEAT` command with an iteration variable ('i' in this case).

```
DO REPEAT ageN = age20 TO age69
         / i = 20 TO 69.
    COMPUTE ageN = (age=i).
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

This Code works as if you would run the following lines:

```
COMPUTE age20 = (age=20). /* If age=20 then age20 = 1 else age20 = 0.
COMPUTE age21 = (age=21).
COMPUTE age22 = (age=22).
...
```

Comment: That's the same solution as provided by Jignesh Sutar but with some more explanation.

Comment: Thanks, knew there would be a easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a single age variable using [RECODE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_recode.htm) command and then aggregate, particularly if your age groups are mutually exclusive (as they are in your example).

```
RECODE AGE
  (lo thru 24=1)
  (lo thru 29=2)
  (lo thru 34=3)
  (lo thru 39=4)
  (lo thru 44=5)
  (lo thru 49=6)
  (lo thru 54=7)
  (lo thru 59=8)
  (lo thru hi=9) INTO AGEGRP.
FORMATS AGEGRP (F3.0).
VARIABLE LABELS AGEGRP "Age Groups".
VALUE LABELS AGEGRP
  1 "<24"
  2 "25-29"
  3 "30-34"
  4 "35-39"
  5 "40-44"
  6 "45-49"
  7 "50-54"
  8 "55-59"
  9 "60+".
```

If for whatever reason you do want to generate dummy codes for all age then try:

```
DO REPEAT AgeZZ=AgeV1_20 to AgeV1_70 /ZZ=20 to 70.
   COMPUTE AgeZZ=Age=ZZ.
END REPEAT.

/* Or alternatively */.
VECTOR AgeV2_(70).
LOOP #i = 1 to 70.
  COMPUTE AgeV2_(#i) = Age = #i.
END LOOP.
```